# ADAL (adal4j) could be used for on-premise?

Tags: adal, adal4j

Dears,

I have a MS CRM 2016 installed with ADFS claim based authentication. The STS server enpoint is available at https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/services/trust/mex.

Is Adal4j can help me to authenticate on my environment ? Or is it onky for Azure/on-line services ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Adal4J does support ADFS. You can see the ADFS authority type [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4j/AuthorityType.java)